# How to access items from array

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to display the name and photoUrl in the HTML template of an Angular 6 app, how do I access the name and photoUrl elements only in the below array:

```
{
   "key":"key0",
   "value":[
      {
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {
     "id":3243242,
     "name":"Ryan",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/male-29.jpg",
     "rating":5
  }
   ]
}

{  
   "key":"key1",
   "value":[  
  {  
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {  
     "id":6757587,
     "name":"Sarah",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-70.jpg",
     "rating":16
  }
   ]
}
```

Comment: your JSON have syntax error!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngFor` directive provided by Angular

**.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
 <div *ngFor="let value of values;i = index">
  <div>{{value.name}}</div>
  <div>{{value.photoUrl}}</div>
 </div>
<div>
```

**.component.ts**

```
users = [
 {
   "key":"key0",
   "value":[
      {
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {
     "id":3243242,
     "name":"Ryan",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/male-29.jpg",
     "rating":5
  }
   ]
}.
{  
   "key":"key1",
   "value":[  
  {  
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {  
     "id":6757587,
     "name":"Sarah",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-70.jpg",
     "rating":16
  }
   ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, however i made few adjustments

> [   {
>       "key": "key0",
>       "value": [
>         {
>           "id": 567657,
>           "name": "Jess",
>           "photoUrl": "https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
>           "rating": 30
>         },
>         {
>           "id": 3243242,
>           "name": "Ryan",
>           "photoUrl": "https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/male-29.jpg",
>           "rating": 5
>         }
>       ]   },   {
>       "key": "key1",
>       "value": [
>         {
>           "id": 567657,
>           "name": "Jess",
>           "photoUrl": "https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
>           "rating": 30
>         },
>         {
>           "id": 6757587,
>           "name": "Sarah",
>           "photoUrl": "https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-70.jpg",
>           "rating": 16
>         }
>       ]   } ]

and you just need nested ngFor as follows,

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let group of myArray">
    {{group.name}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let light of group.value">
            <h1>Photo </h1>  {{light.photoUrl}}
            <h1>Name </h1>    {{light.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qobbby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

**component.ts**

```
user_Array = [
 {
   "key":"key0",
   "value":[
      {
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {
     "id":3243242,
     "name":"Ryan",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/male-29.jpg",
     "rating":5
  }
   ]
}.
{  
   "key":"key1",
   "value":[  
  {  
     "id":567657,
     "name":"Jess",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-50.jpeg",
     "rating":30
  },
  {  
     "id":6757587,
     "name":"Sarah",
     "photoUrl":"https://d3iw72m71ie81c.cloudfront.net/female-70.jpg",
     "rating":16
  }
   ]
 }
]
```

**component.html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let user of user_Array">
     <span>{{user?.name}}</span>
     <img src="{{user?.photoUrl}}">

    <div>
```

**comment**
by adding '?' html file will not generate error if that specific variable is not present.
it is always safe to add "?" while accessing ts variable